# How to unlock each product when user purchase the product , Firebase flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I need a solution, I'm developing an online course selling app, and I want to unlock the course when users purchase the product. how do I do that, I've received Firebase autogenerated course id when the new course and each episode were added. so how do I implement this logic?

and I locked the course using `if else` widget checking.

here is how I done that
[image]

I also have no idea this is the right way to do this,
how do I implement this logic to the app,

Comment: This question is impossible to answer as we don't know how a course is 'locked' in the first place. What does 'locked' mean in relation to how your data is stored? We really need a lot more to go on. Please take a moment and review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Jay hey jay, please check edited question

Comment: It's not clear what the image in the question represents - how does that 'lock' a course? Also, how does it correlate to Firestore? SO is not a good interactive debugger and not a good place to ask for help with app level design decisions as we would have to know your entire use case to tell you how to create a Firebase structure (if that's what you're asking). We are here to help with existing code. Do you have some code you're having difficulty with?

Comment: This question is way to broad to answer and concerns general programming advice. Check out the Firestore documentation instead. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/

Answer (score 0):

Save list id courses of user data, and check if list id exists on user data when user access the course then unlock this